# eregi to pregmatch not working

Tags: php, preg-match

How do i change this to NOT alphanumeric? (on google i see all that do want alphanumeric)

Code :

```
         /* Check if username is not alphanumeric */
     else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9,]+$/", $subuser)){
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
     }
```

it keeps saying

```
* Username not alphanumeric
```

this was the old part when i had it with eregi

```
         /* Check if username is not alphanumeric */
     else if(!eregi("^([0-9a-z])+$", $subuser)){
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
     }
```

Comment: what is the username your trying to match

Comment: just a random like "edrftgy" just for testing

Comment: strange behavior i see http://codepad.org/2r0pOjyc but works on my local machine,

Comment: @DevZer0 i'm getting a error there?

Comment: read the link i put as a comment about the error. the error is related to codepad runtime environment being restrictive. unless your server has the same issue your regexp should work.

Comment: @JacobBrol Can you give an example for a user name that works not as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easist way with regex is to use a `^` inside the `[]` character class to negate it:

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $subuser)) {
    //contains at least one non alpha-num character.
}
```

However, PHP also supplies a built-in function for this: [`ctype_alnum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

```
if(!ctype_alnum($subuser)) { .... }
```

Comment: Both these options should work. Can you clarify exactly what error you're getting? Have you tried it in a small test program on its own?

Comment: `pret_match` gives `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 4 in`

and `ctype-alnum` gives hmm thats weird it seems to work now

Comment: if ctype_alnum works for you, then great (it's probably a better option than regex anyway). But for the preg -- I had a capital `Z` in the preg code; should have been lower case. try it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [special character class identifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) `:alnum:` together with the `,` and negate it with `^`:

```
if(!preg_match("/[^:alnum:,]+$/", $subuser))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9,]+$/"` to `"/[^a-zA-Z0-9,]+/"` and try

Comment: then is not match means doesn't include alpha numeric chars